How to create a flexible laravel eloquent search function
I'm trying to create a search function for my laravel project.
What I want to achieve is that, for example, I have a companies table, and company name is ABC-Company. I want ABC-Company to be the search result when people uses the search keywords:
ABC Company, ABCCompany, ABC-Company.
Here is my existing logic:
if ($conditions['keyword']) {
        $query->where(function ($q) use ($conditions) {
            $q->where('company.name', 'like', '%' . $conditions['keyword'] . '%')
                ->orWhere('company.description', 'like', '%' . $conditions['keyword'] . '%')
                ->orWhere('categories.name', 'like', '%' . $conditions['keyword'] . '%')
        });
    }

The search can still find if it is the exact match, if it has space instead of the special character, or if it has no space or no special characters (e.g. -).
I did try several options like using preg_replace on the keyword and on the query builder. removing the spaces and special characters.
Also tried replacing the special characters or spaces with '%', however, the result is incorrect when searching for the keyword without spaces. ABCCompany will not return the ABC-Company value
but non of them worked.
Thank you.

I would use a 3 step approach to achieve this.

I will normalize the search so to improve the search. I will use this command return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $term);
I will create a scope in the model to handle the search public function scopeSearch()
Implement my search logic in the scope

